# How can I evaluate surface integral in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

$$\iint_{S^+}x^3dydz $$where $S$ bottom part of $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

$S^+$ - outer side of $S$

[image: ellipsoid with normals]

$$\iint_{S^+}P(x,y,z)dydz = \iint_{S}P\cos\alpha dS,\ \;  normal : \vec{n}=(cos\alpha, cos\beta, cos\gamma)$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your domain definition. What do you mean by "$S$ [is the] bottom part" of that ellipsoid? And do you mean by $S^+$ the surface of $S$ for positive $z$?

Comment: @MarcoB My take is that it's the flux integral of the vector field `{x^3, 0, 0}` over the portion of the oriented surface where `z <= 0`, with the standard positive orientiation away from the interior of the (whole) ellipsoid.  I don't see how it could be anything else.  It's not a particularly hard integral, but my *Mathematica* is busy right now.  I'm not sure whether the OP wants to know how to set up the surface integral or one can use the divergence theorem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That makes sense, thank you. My vector calculus is awfully rusty, but at least now I understand the problem, and I can play with it for a bit of fun.

Comment: Does this seem like what you're after?: `Clear[DoubleContourIntegral];
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
  surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}),
    {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, v2_}}] := Integrate[
  Dot[field /. Thread[changeOfVars], Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]],
  {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];

Clear[a, b, c];
S = {{x, y, z} -> {a Sin[u] Cos[v], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[u]}, {u, 
   Pi/2, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}}; F = {x^3, 0, 0};
\[DoubleContourIntegral] F \[DifferentialD]S`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Is it pattern?

Comment: No, I defined a generic surface integral of a vector field and applied it to your problem.  The main code is the `Integrate`. For your example,  `S` is the parametrization of the half-ellipsoid and `F` is the field being integrated.  Does it not work if you copy/paste/execute it in *Mathematica*?  Sorry if it's too complicate.  I thought a general function would be useful to others, too, instead of just focusing on a single problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes, copy-past work. As magic for me. But whats strange, in topic http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286549/integration-of-surface, man with big rate said that's result must be 0. I think, he didn't understand my question and solve just integral by dS.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought i can use this theorem then surface is closed like sphere. As i see, it was wrong? Thank you for responding on math forum

Comment: @MichaelE2 Amazing, i got it

Comment: Panda, I think Micheal has provided an excellent answer to your question. Would you consider accepting it?

Comment: @MarcoB yes, l slept, sorry

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
Clear[DoubleContourIntegral]; 
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
  surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}),
  {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, v2_}}] :=
   Integrate[
    Dot[field /. Thread[changeOfVars], 
      Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];

Clear[a, b, c];
S = {{x, y, z} -> {a Sin[u] Cos[v], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[u]}, {u, 
    Pi/2, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}};
F = {x^3, 0, 0};

\[DoubleContourIntegral] F \[DifferentialD]S
(*  2/5 a^3 b c π  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The symbol [`\[DoubleContourIntegral]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/DoubleContourIntegral.html) is interpreted as `DoubleContourIntegral`, which is itself undefined.  So I defined it to perform a surface integral of a vector field (flux), where the surface is defined by a parametrization `surface`.  The parametrization consists of a rule that defines `{x, y, z}` in terms of parametric functions and domains for the two parameters.  The integrand is the dot product of the vector field with the cross product of the two partial derivatives of the parametrization, which is the standard definition.  This definition can be applied to other parametrized surfaces and other vector fields.  Note that care should be taken to make sure that the parametrization has the desired orientation.

(The OP's notation is not the same as the notation in standard US textbooks but it is equivalent to $\iint (P, 0, 0) \dot \;d{\bf S}$.)

Comment: Michael, thank you for taking the time to turn your comment into a full answer. I was hoping you would when I asked to have the question reopened! I wonder if I could press you into including the alternative approach using the divergence theorem as well. (+1)

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1288004 - Let me know if that is sufficient.

Comment: That will do nicely, thank you!

Comment: Excellent, thank you)

Comment: @MichaelE2 When I use your code to calculate the problems in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286549/integrating-the-vector-field-over-the-bottom-half-of-the-oriented-ellipsoid/1288004#1288004) , the following code cannot return the results:`S = {({x, y, z} -> {u, v, Sqrt[1 - u^2/a^2 - v^2/b^2]}), {u, -a, 
    a}, {v, -b*Sqrt[1 - u^2/a^2], b*Sqrt[1 - u^2/a^2]}};
F = {x^3, 0, 0};`.In addition, I have a similar problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226708/how-to-calculate-this-surface-integral). Can you spare time to have a look?

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 That's a problem with `Integrate`. In this case, it helps to include the assumptions about the parameters you have in mind.  Try `Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0,\[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S]`. In general, it's better to use the `Assumptions` option to `Integrate`, but the `\[DoubleContourIntegral]` input notation doesn't allow for passing options. One could add options to `DoubleContourIntegral[]` or do it this way: `Block[{Integrate = Inactive[Integrate]}, \[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S] // Append[Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0] // Activate`

Answer (score 2):

In *v13.3* `SurfaceIntegrate` has been introduced, so the problem can be solved as follows:

```
reg = 
  ParametricRegion[{a Sin[u] Cos[v], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[u]}, 
                   {{u, Pi/2, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}}];

SurfaceIntegrate[{x^3, 0, 0}, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]
(* 2/5 a^3 b c π *)
```

Sadly the following still returns the input for the moment:

```
SurfaceIntegrate[{x^3, 0, 0}, {x, y, z} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 == 1 && z < 0, {x, y, z}]]
(* Input returned *)
```