# Calculating a surface integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

How to calculate the following surface integral using MichaelE2's `DoubleContourIntegral` ([How can I evaluate surface integral in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83681/how-can-i-evaluate-surface-integral-in-mathematica/83797#83797)),

$$\iint_{\Sigma} x^{2} \mathrm{~d} y \mathrm{~d} z+y^{2} \mathrm{~d} z \mathrm{~d} x+z^{2} \mathrm{~d} x \mathrm{~d} y$$

Where $\Sigma$ is the outside of the entire surface of the cuboid $\Omega$:

$\{(x, y, z) \mid 0 \leqslant x \leqslant a, 0 \leqslant y \leqslant b, 0 \leqslant z\leqslant c\}$

Result: $(a+b+c) a b c$

PS.  MichaelE2's `DoubleContourIntegral`, e.g. $\iint_{S^{+}} x^{3} d y d z$

where $S$ is the bottom part of $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}}=1\;$
$S_+$ - outer side of $S$

$\iint_{S^{+}} P(x, y, z) d y d z=\iint_{S} P \cos \alpha d S$, normal $: \vec{n}=(\cos \alpha, \cos \beta, \cos \gamma)$

```
Clear[DoubleContourIntegral];
DoubleContourIntegral[field_?VectorQ, 
   surface : {changeOfVars : ({x_, y_, z_} -> 
        param : {xuv_, yuv_, zuv_}), {u_, u1_, u2_}, {v_, v1_, 
      v2_}}] := 
  Integrate[
   Dot[field /. Thread[changeOfVars], 
    Cross[D[param, u], D[param, v]]], {u, u1, u2}, {v, v1, v2}];

Clear[a, b, c];
S = {{x, y, z} -> {a Sin[u] Cos[v], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[u]}, {u, 
    Pi/2, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}};
F = {x^3, 0, 0};
\[DoubleContourIntegral]F \[DifferentialD]S
```

> ```
> 2/5 a^3 b c Pi
> ```

Updated:

Thanks for Artes's answer.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
F[x_, y_, z_] := {x^2, y^2, z^2};
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   0 <= x <= a && 0 <= y <= b && 0 <= z <= c, {x, y, z}];
Integrate[Div[F[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} \[Element] reg, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0] // Simplify
```

> ```
> a b c (a + b + c)
> ```

In my textbook, it is called Gauss formula.
$\iiint_{\Omega}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial R}{\partial z}\right) \mathrm{d} v=\iint_{\Sigma} P \mathrm{~d} y \mathrm{~d} z+Q \mathrm{~d} z \mathrm{~d} x+R \mathrm{~d} x \mathrm{~d} y$

Can there be a general code for finding the unit vector of the normal outside the surface? So we can integrate directly. Especially for non closed surfaces.

Comment: There are surface integrals of the first and second kind. See [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Surface_integral) for info.

Comment: Thanks. The surface integral in my question is second kind. I just want to find a way to integrate directly. Such as MichaelE2's method. @user64494

Answer (score 5):

Using [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem) ($\;\int_{\partial \Omega} \omega = \int_\Omega d\omega \;$) this surface integral can be recast as  an integral of exterior derivative of the given differential form over the given volume, here  $\Omega$ is the cuboid, $\partial \Omega$ is its surface (boundary), $\omega=x^2 dy \wedge dz+y^2 dz \wedge dx+ z^2 dx \wedge dy\;$ and $$d\omega = d(x^2 dy \wedge dz+y^2 dz \wedge dx+ z^2 dx \wedge dy)= 2(x+y+z)\; dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$$
Now this could be calculated in mind, however if there must be a powerful technology let there be

```
Integrate[2 (x + y + z), {z, 0, c}, {y, 0, b}, {x, 0, a}]
```

> ```
>  a b c (a + b + c)
> ```

There is (in *Mathematica*) a convention that in multiple integrals the outermost integral (here $\int_0^a f\; d x\;$)is calculated first. This is the simplest approach and it shouldn't be replaced by other more involved methods.

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you say, but I have a different view of the convention, namely, that in `Integrate[f[x, y, z], {z, 0, c}, {y, 0, b}, {x, 0, a}]`, the iterators proceed from outer to inner, so that $\int_0^a f \; dx$ is the innermost integral. One might view it as applying integration operators in the order $(\int_0^c dz)\left[(\int_0^b dy)\left[(\int_0^a dx)\left[f(x,y,z)\right]\right]\right]$,  even the `Integrate` code is typeset as $\int _0^c\int _0^b\int _0^a f(x,y,z)\;dx\,dy\,dz$

Comment: In my post the outermost term regarded the last one in `Integrate[f, {z, 0, c}, {y, 0, b}, {x, 0, a}]` i.e. `{x, 0, a}` and this is compatibile with your comment.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question. @Artes

Answer (score 2):

In *v13.3* `SurfaceIntegrate` is introduced, so the problem can be solved as follows:

```
SurfaceIntegrate[{x^2, y^2, z^2}, {x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]] // Simplify
(* a b c (a + b + c) *)
```

[image]